# How to use $wpdb class in WordPress and in which file to use its functions?

Tags: wordpress

I'm not familiar with how to use `$wpdb` class and its functions to fire queries and getting and displaying results and in which file to use them in WordPress. Please give solution step by step.

Comment: Read this: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb, maybe it can help you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Questions asking for general help are discouraged.Before posting a question, it is expected that you have researched your issue and made a good attempt to write the code yourself. If you get stuck on something *specific*, come back and include a summary of what you have tried and the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$wpdb is not a function it is global object variable actually wordpress has defines a class called wpdb.

Basically when you required the database connection you need to write $wpdb.

In the simplest terms possible $wpdb is how the database is accessed 99% of the time on a WordPress site. It’s WordPress’s database interacting agent.

For example :

```
global $wpdb;
$posts = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts, OBJECT );
```

Hope you get the understanding. For more understanding please read this [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb).

Comment: Hello ,Can You Suggest Me Please In Which File I have To Write Code  For That In Wordpress?

Comment: You can write in any file but for ideal practice use on those function where you really not getting the database connection.

Comment: Are you getting what i mean to say?

Comment: Ok Thanks ,I Got It